# Any secondary uses for taffy?

Tags: culinary-uses, candy, taffy

My sister got married recently and had a candy buffet at the wedding.  Their colors were yellow and gray, and we now have a *lot* of leftover banana taffy.  We're never going to eat it all at the rate that we're going, and Halloween is still a long way off.  Are there any secondary uses for taffy?  I've searched for recipes *containing* taffy (as an ingredient) but haven't been able to find any.  Are there any candies that have a taffy-like stage on the way to something else?

Comment: Another wedding? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound odd, but taffy is actually a great ingredient in sweeter coffee drinks like mochas.  It melts into the drink adding sugar and flavor.  I'm a fan of banana for this purpose.

In a similar vein, you could also use the taffy as a chip in cookies.  Chop it up and use it wherever you think banana flavor would taste good.  I could imagine the banana taffy going well in with macadamia nuts.  You might want to consider the taffy as a substitute for butterscotch or white chocolate chips in recipes requiring them.

Comment: Coffee + banana?? Doesn't sound terribly appetizing.

Comment: @Marti - it's the + chocolate part that makes it good in my opinion, but banana candy in my experience tends to be one of those polarizing flavors

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I have softened taffy in the microwave thus making it pliable, then wrapped the soft taffy around an apple. This may sound unorthodox, but I find this to be an effective way to deal with any surplus taffy.

Answer (score -1):

Ever tried a "banoffee" pie or cheesecake?

They can benefit from some smashed up toffee (I'm English, we call it toffee) in the mix and certainly on the top.

Another alternative is just to let it go stale, it just becomes fudge like usually after a considerable time and is perfectly pleasant.

Comment: (suggested by anon user): Taffy and toffee are very different. Taffy is soft, stretchy & chewy, as long as it's fresh. It doesn't get hard & crushable like toffee, although it can get hard and more difficult to chew as it gets older. It will definitely not become fudge-like as it ages, just harder.

Comment: @rumtscho: Granted, whilst *taffy* does exist in places in the UK, we never really use the concept.  However, toffee does come in many variations and much toffee that is sold is more similar to taffy in physical properties.